# using table row as a hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a drop down menu that is a table and table rows. Each row contains a word which is a hyperlink text. I would like the blank space following the hyperlink word to be a link to the same url as the text itself.

This is what i have so far

```
<TR ID="opt_1" onclick href="boom.php?catname=booyah " ONMOUSEOVER="hiLiteM('01'); hiLite('1')" ONMOUSEOUT="unLite('1'); unLiteM('01')" ><TD> <a onclick href="boom.php?catname=booyah ">booyah</A></TD></TR>
```

This doesn't work, are the any suggestions for me to achieve success, thank you

Comment: One interesting thing I find is that you are capitalizing almost every tag, and the `onclick` is empty for no apparent reason. Enlighten me, why do you do that?

Comment: temporary retardation

Answer (score 1):

You can style the anchor as a block element and it will fill the entire cell.  Since there's only one cell in your row, I think this should accomplish what you want without need for javascript:

```
<tr id="opt_1">
    <td><a style="display: block" href="boom.php?catname=booyah">booyah</a></td>
</tr>
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hvcjjnb/)

I'm not sure what those mouseover and mouseout functions do but I'm assuming they are styling changes that could just as easily be accomplished with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TR ID="opt_2" onClick="location.href='brands.php?catname=Asprey'" ONMOUSEOVER="hiLiteM('01');hiLite('2')" ONMOUSEOUT="unLite('2'); unLiteM('01')"><TD><A  onclick href="brands.php?catname=Asprey">Asprey</A></TD></TR>
```

This is my solution. does anyone have anything better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make the whole td as hyperlink by placeing anchor tag inside td and giving class with width of 100% to anchor tag.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hvcjjnb/2/)

**CSS**

```
table { width: 300px; }

table, table tr, table td
{
margin:0%;
}

.td-link
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    background:aqua;
}

a
{
   text-decoration:none;
    color:black;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <a href="abc.html" class="td-link">TD is made link now </a>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```